# Chrome: SVG container not rescaling responsively

Tags: css, svg, responsive-design

I have an SVG that is effectively being used as a 'mask'; it's displayed over the top of another div with a background image so that the image peeks through the unfilled areas of the SVG. The SVG itself is responsive to the height of the document (rather than the width). This works fine so far.

However, I've just been made aware that if you resize the (Chrome) browser, the background image overflows out of the bounds of the masking SVG; however, if you refresh the resized page, everything appears as expected - it *only* occurs on resize, and only in Chrome (oh, and Opera too, apparently). Works as expected in FF and Safari.

I've included a demo here (and a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbg1g4uv/1/)) with an inline SVG, however it doesn't seem to matter if it's inline or with an `<img />` tag - the results are the same.

It seems to be somehow related to the containing element; if I open up the inspector and set the containing element's `padding` to `0` after it goes screwy, then it seems to figure itself out and suddenly appear as expected; however if I include that rule in the loaded CSS then it makes no difference. I even tried triggering similar CSS properties on page resize via Javascript, but it hasn't made any difference.

Am I missing something, or have I stumbled across a bug?

```css
#splash {
  position:               relative;
  height:                 100vh;
  padding:                3rem;
  overflow:               hidden;
  display:                flex;
  -webkit-box-align:      center;
  align-items:            center;
  background-color:       #DDDDDD;
}

#logowrapper {
  position:               relative;
  width:                  auto;
  height:                 60%;
  margin:                 auto;
}

#logowrapper .kitten {
  position:               absolute;
  top:                    0;
  left:                   0;
  bottom:                 0;
  right:                  0;
  background-image:       url('http://placekitten.com/200/300');
  background-size:        cover;
}

#logowrapper svg {
  position:               relative;
  width:                  auto;
  height:                 100%;
  z-index:                4;
}
```

```html
<div id="splash">
  <div id="logowrapper">
    <div class="kitten"></div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 200 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <defs/>
  <g>
    <path stroke="none" fill="#DDDDDD" d="M110.95 215.1 Q100 225.6 100 240.7 100 256.25 110.75 266.85 121.45 277.5 137 277.5 153.9 277.5 165.45 267.4 177 257.35 177 242.5 177 226.85 166.7 216.1 155.6 204.6 137.5 204.6 121.85 204.6 110.95 215.1 M82.9 206.15 L82.2 206.05 80.3 206.05 Q75.15 206.05 71.55 207.25 66.35 208.95 66.35 212.7 66.35 215.65 67.75 216.9 L69.25 218.45 Q69.25 220.6 67.05 223.4 64.85 226.1 64.05 226.1 L63.8 226.1 Q62.45 225.9 60.35 223.3 58.25 220.75 58.25 218.4 58.25 217.8 59.6 217.1 60.95 216.3 60.95 214.7 L60.85 213.3 Q60.35 210.15 57.05 208.5 53.7 206.9 50.15 206.9 L32.8 206.9 27.25 207.75 Q21.85 209.3 21.85 213.1 21.85 214.8 23.35 216.2 24.85 217.8 28.4 219.3 29.9 219.9 35.1 226.2 40.3 232.5 44.5 239.15 45.2 240.05 45.4 242.35 L45.6 248.15 45.4 255.5 45 261.5 Q45 263.1 42.8 264.65 38.2 267.8 38.2 269.6 38.2 274.8 45.2 275.9 L58.55 276.5 61.45 276.5 64.35 276.6 Q69.45 276.6 72.2 275.6 75.85 274.1 77.25 270.45 L77.45 269.1 Q77.45 267.2 75.15 265.6 70.45 262.25 70.45 259.55 L70.45 238.95 86.05 218.7 Q86.3 218.45 91.45 216.9 95.1 215.75 95.1 212.05 95.1 208.35 93.45 207.15 91.6 205.95 88.5 205.95 L85.65 206.05 82.9 206.15 M127.75 222.3 Q130.15 219.2 133.85 219.2 141.8 219.2 146.9 232 151 242.15 151 251.7 151 256.7 148.6 259.6 146.2 262.4 142.2 262.4 135.1 262.4 129.75 249.5 125.35 238.95 125.35 230.4 125.35 225.5 127.75 222.3 M127 174.1 Q127.35 173.5 128.35 173.5 132.6 173.5 132.6 178.95 132.6 183.25 129 183.25 127.35 183.25 126.95 181.7 126.7 180.85 126.7 178.2 L126.65 176.9 126.6 175.7 Q126.6 174.7 127 174.1 M126.85 160.15 Q127.2 159.3 128.05 159.3 131.5 159.3 131.5 164.2 131.5 168.75 127.95 168.75 127.1 168.75 126.8 167.9 126.45 167.1 126.45 165.75 L126.5 164.8 126.6 163.8 126.55 163.5 126.5 162.2 Q126.5 161 126.85 160.15 M111.95 158.35 Q112.35 159 113.1 159 114.4 159 115.05 161.55 115.65 164.15 115.65 168.15 115.65 173.9 114.65 179 113.65 184.1 112.3 184.1 111.75 184.1 111.55 184.55 L111.35 185.8 Q111.35 186.95 112.3 187.65 113.2 188.35 114.7 188.35 L119.6 188.2 124.9 188.05 129.2 188.2 133.15 188.35 Q139 188.35 142.5 185.45 145.95 182.6 145.95 177.7 145.95 173.8 142.8 171.8 139.6 169.85 139.6 169.4 L142 166.2 Q143.1 164.4 143.1 162.15 143.1 157.75 139.35 155.9 136.65 154.55 131.8 154.55 L127.55 154.65 121.75 154.75 118.8 154.65 114.9 154.55 Q113.4 154.55 112.45 155.25 111.5 155.95 111.5 157 111.5 157.75 111.95 158.35 M106.65 123.3 L103.7 123.4 97.65 123.4 95.55 123.65 Q95.05 123.9 95.05 124.6 95.05 125.15 95.75 125.45 96.4 125.7 96.6 126 97.15 127.2 97.15 131.75 L97.05 134.45 96.8 136.4 Q96.6 137.2 95.9 137.6 95.2 137.95 95.2 138.45 95.2 139.45 96.45 139.45 L106.35 139.45 108.1 139.65 109.05 139.7 Q109.8 139.7 110.55 137.9 L111.2 135.45 110.9 134.3 Q110.55 133.9 110.05 133.9 109.7 133.9 108.65 135.5 107.5 137.1 104.5 137.1 102.9 137.1 102.55 136.65 102.25 136.15 102.25 133.95 102.25 133 102.4 132.65 102.6 132.35 103.15 132.35 104.35 132.35 104.65 133.55 104.9 134.75 105.45 134.75 106.15 134.75 106.6 133.75 107 132.7 107 131.05 107 129.4 106.65 128.5 106.25 127.6 105.6 127.6 104.8 127.6 104.6 128.85 104.35 130.1 103.5 130.1 L102.3 129.95 Q102.05 129.8 102.05 129.05 L102.05 127.05 Q102.05 126.2 102.45 125.9 L104 125.65 Q107.05 125.65 108 127.2 L109 127.85 Q110.25 127.85 110.25 126.2 110.25 124.95 109.65 123.95 109.1 122.95 108.4 122.95 L106.65 123.3 M150.65 132.95 L149.4 132.85 148.85 132.5 Q148.85 132.05 149.45 130.75 150 129.5 150.4 129.5 L151.55 130.75 Q152.3 132.05 152.3 132.55 L151.85 132.85 150.65 132.95 M158.5 133.55 Q156.15 128.3 155.2 126.7 153 123.05 150.85 123.05 148.25 123.05 148.25 126 L147.2 129.6 Q146.05 132.8 144.95 134.8 143.55 137.4 142.8 137.4 142.3 137.4 142.1 137.7 141.95 137.95 141.95 138.35 141.95 139.1 142.75 139.4 L145.5 139.7 Q148.9 139.7 148.9 138.3 148.9 137.75 148.2 137.5 147.45 137.2 147.45 136.9 147.45 136.1 147.85 135.9 L149.95 135.65 150.55 135.65 152.8 135.85 Q153.55 136.05 153.55 136.75 L153.1 137.3 Q152.15 137.75 152.15 138.35 152.15 139.25 153.5 139.45 L157.4 139.7 160.8 139.3 Q161.8 138.95 161.8 138.05 161.8 137.25 160.95 137.25 160.2 137.25 158.5 133.55 M125.05 123.2 L122.1 123.6 Q121.05 124.05 121.05 124.8 121.05 125.6 121.55 125.8 122.3 126.15 122.65 127.1 L126.95 138.15 Q127.3 139.05 127.75 139.4 128.15 139.75 128.9 139.75 130.15 139.75 131.15 137.75 L132.5 134.15 Q133.15 132.2 133.65 132.2 134.25 132.2 134.95 134.15 L136.25 137.75 Q137.2 139.7 138.45 139.7 139.2 139.7 139.65 139.15 L140.85 136.8 144.35 127.65 Q144.95 126.15 145.5 125.6 146.2 125 146.2 124.6 146.2 123.15 143.5 123.15 141.8 123.15 141 123.5 140.25 123.8 140.25 124.5 140.25 125.25 141 125.55 141.75 125.85 141.75 126.25 L141.05 128.7 Q140.35 130.45 139.95 130.45 139.6 130.45 138.7 128.75 137.8 127.05 137.8 126.15 L138.1 125.55 138.8 124.55 Q138.8 123.85 137.8 123.5 L134.45 123.2 Q130 123.2 130 124.65 130 125.2 130.95 126.05 131.95 126.9 131.95 127.6 L131.6 129.15 Q131.15 130.7 130.5 130.7 130.1 130.7 129.3 128.55 128.55 126.6 128.55 126.15 L128.75 125.6 129.1 124.65 Q129.1 123.8 128.25 123.5 L125.05 123.2 M58.85 159.05 Q53.65 164.05 53.65 171.25 53.65 178.65 58.75 183.7 63.85 188.75 71.25 188.75 79.3 188.75 84.8 183.95 90.3 179.15 90.3 172.1 90.3 164.65 85.4 159.55 80.1 154.05 71.5 154.05 64.05 154.05 58.85 159.05 M69.75 161 Q73.55 161 76 167.1 77.95 171.95 77.95 176.5 77.95 178.85 76.8 180.25 75.65 181.6 73.75 181.6 70.35 181.6 67.8 175.45 65.7 170.4 65.7 166.35 65.7 164 66.85 162.5 68 161 69.75 161 M25.65 154.5 L24.4 154.2 Q21.85 154.2 19.85 157.7 18.1 160.75 18.1 163.25 18.1 164.7 18.8 165.85 19.45 167 20.65 167 22.7 167 24.8 164.3 26.9 161.6 27.55 161.6 28.6 161.6 29 162.95 29.4 164.35 29.4 166.75 L29.3 169.4 29.2 172.6 29 176.6 28.3 180.95 Q28.1 181.7 26.3 182.65 24.5 183.6 24.5 184.55 24.5 186.9 28.1 187.75 L34.9 188.3 Q40.5 188.3 42.7 187.3 44.95 186.35 44.95 184.7 44.95 183.35 43.15 182.65 41.4 182 41.2 181.25 40.55 178.55 40.4 177.05 L40.2 173 Q40.2 169 40.5 165.25 40.8 161.5 41.4 161.5 43.35 161.5 44.6 164.15 45.85 166.8 48.4 166.8 49.9 166.8 50.95 165.65 52 164.5 52 162.9 52 160.4 50.6 157.45 48.95 154.05 46.6 154.05 L46.3 154.05 45.35 154.35 44.15 154.7 26.95 154.8 25.65 154.5 M29.4 123.45 L28.55 123.45 Q26.1 123.45 25.05 123.95 24.2 124.35 24.2 125.1 24.2 125.45 24.65 125.8 25.65 126.55 25.75 127.3 L25.85 129.35 25.85 129.75 25.85 130.15 25.75 132.8 25.7 135.35 Q25.7 136.4 24.5 137.05 23.95 137.35 23.95 137.75 23.95 138.9 25.25 139.25 L27.9 139.5 28.65 139.5 31.45 139.3 Q32.9 139 32.9 138.2 32.9 137.65 32.2 136.95 L31.4 135.8 31.35 134.15 31.25 132.35 31.4 129.05 31.5 127.1 Q31.5 126.8 32.45 125.9 32.9 125.5 32.9 124.95 32.9 123.95 31.8 123.65 L29.4 123.45 M43.05 123.3 L41.3 123.1 Q38.5 123.1 36.6 124.65 34.7 126.25 34.7 128.6 34.7 130.8 36.75 132.3 37.7 133 40.5 134.2 42.55 135.1 42.55 135.75 42.55 136.25 42 136.55 L40.6 136.85 Q38.35 136.85 37.05 135.05 35.7 133.25 35.25 133.25 34.25 133.25 34.25 134.55 34.25 137.15 35.6 138.3 37.2 139.75 41.45 139.75 44.7 139.75 46.75 138.2 48.8 136.6 48.8 134.05 48.8 131.65 46.75 130.35 45.95 129.85 42.95 128.8 40.9 128.1 40.9 127.2 40.9 126.65 41.3 126.35 41.7 126.05 42.35 126.05 43.55 126.05 45.05 127.35 46.55 128.7 47.2 128.7 47.75 128.7 48.15 128.2 48.55 127.75 48.55 127.1 48.55 126.1 47.75 124.85 46.95 123.45 46 123.45 L45.4 123.6 44.9 123.75 43.05 123.3 M80 123.35 L77.15 123.6 Q75.65 123.95 75.65 125 75.65 125.55 76.15 125.75 L77.1 126.45 77.35 127.6 77.4 130.25 77.25 134.5 76.8 136.8 76 137.15 Q75.5 137.3 75.5 137.9 75.5 138.95 76.95 139.35 L79.6 139.6 82.45 139.3 Q84.05 138.9 84.05 138.05 L84.05 137.95 Q84.05 137.5 83.6 137.15 82.5 136.35 82.5 134.5 82.5 133.45 82.8 133.05 83.25 132.5 84.7 132.5 L86.4 132.7 Q86.75 132.9 86.75 133.45 L86.7 133.9 86.7 134.35 Q86.7 136.55 85.65 137.2 85.2 137.5 85.2 138.2 85.2 138.95 86.6 139.4 L89.1 139.7 91.4 139.6 Q93.75 139.3 93.75 138.05 93.75 137.5 93.25 137.3 92.25 136.85 92.25 132.5 92.25 126.5 93.45 125.75 94 125.4 94 124.85 94 124 92.65 123.6 L90.15 123.25 87.8 123.4 Q85.3 123.75 85.3 124.9 85.3 125.3 86.05 125.9 86.8 126.5 86.8 128.1 L86.65 129.45 Q86.5 129.75 85.8 129.75 L85.35 129.7 84.9 129.7 84.4 129.75 83.95 129.75 Q83.2 129.75 82.95 129.45 82.6 129.1 82.6 128.05 82.6 126.45 83.8 125.75 84.2 125.45 84.2 124.95 L84.2 124.85 Q84.1 123.85 82.65 123.5 L80 123.35 M62.25 123.35 L61.65 123.15 Q60.45 123.15 59.5 124.85 58.65 126.3 58.65 127.5 58.65 128.2 59 128.75 59.3 129.35 59.85 129.35 60.85 129.35 61.85 128 62.85 126.75 63.2 126.75 63.7 126.75 63.9 127.4 L64.05 129.2 64 130.45 64 132 63.9 133.95 63.55 136 62.6 136.85 Q61.75 137.3 61.75 137.75 61.75 138.9 63.45 139.3 L66.7 139.55 70.45 139.05 Q71.5 138.6 71.5 137.8 71.5 137.2 70.7 136.85 69.85 136.5 69.75 136.15 L69.35 134.15 69.25 132.2 Q69.25 130.3 69.4 128.5 69.55 126.7 69.85 126.7 70.75 126.7 71.35 127.95 71.95 129.25 73.2 129.25 73.9 129.25 74.4 128.65 74.9 128.1 74.9 127.35 74.9 126.15 74.25 124.75 73.45 123.1 72.35 123.1 L72.2 123.1 71.75 123.25 71.15 123.4 62.9 123.45 62.25 123.35 M24.6 90.45 Q21.7 90.45 21.7 94.35 21.7 102.15 25.7 105.65 30.55 110.05 43.2 110.05 53 110.05 59.2 105.3 65.35 100.55 65.35 92.95 65.35 85.7 59.2 81.75 56.8 80.25 47.7 77.15 41.55 75.05 41.55 72.35 41.55 70.65 42.8 69.75 44 68.85 46 68.85 49.6 68.85 54.05 72.8 58.5 76.8 60.5 76.8 62.2 76.8 63.35 75.4 64.5 74.05 64.5 72.05 64.5 69 62.2 65.25 59.7 61.15 56.95 61.15 56.25 61.15 55.15 61.6 L53.55 62.05 48 60.6 42.8 60 Q34.4 60 28.7 64.75 23 69.5 23 76.5 23 83.15 29.1 87.7 32 89.75 40.45 93.4 46.5 96 46.5 98 46.5 99.45 44.9 100.35 43.25 101.3 40.75 101.3 33.95 101.3 30 95.85 26.05 90.45 24.6 90.45 M24.1 34.7 Q24.1 33.75 24.95 33.75 26.55 33.75 26.55 36.05 26.55 38.25 24.6 38.25 24.2 38.25 24.1 38.1 23.95 37.9 23.95 37.5 L24.1 34.7 M19.6 31.3 Q16.95 31.3 16.95 32.7 16.95 33.2 17.5 33.45 18.7 33.95 18.7 37 L18.65 41.9 Q18.65 44.55 17.5 45.25 16.95 45.6 16.95 46.05 16.95 47.7 21.3 47.7 L24.6 47.35 Q25.6 47.05 25.6 46.25 25.6 45.7 25.1 45.4 24.1 44.8 24.1 42.25 L24.1 41.95 24.2 41.15 Q24.3 40.75 24.8 40.75 26.05 40.75 26.6 42.6 27.5 45.7 27.75 46.05 28.85 47.9 31.5 47.9 L34.15 47.45 Q35.15 46.95 35.15 46.15 35.15 45.6 34.35 45.3 33.5 45 33.4 43.9 33.1 41.6 32.1 40.55 31.2 39.55 30.2 39.2 L31.75 37.75 Q32.5 36.85 32.5 35.45 32.5 33.55 30.95 32.4 29.4 31.2 26.85 31.2 L24.05 31.4 22.35 31.45 21 31.35 19.6 31.3 M76.35 33.8 Q77.4 33.8 78 34.5 78.6 35.2 78.6 36.45 78.6 37.7 78.05 38.35 77.5 39 76.5 39 L75.7 38.8 75.45 38.25 75.45 34.25 Q75.45 33.8 76.35 33.8 M42.9 33.9 L44.45 33.65 Q47.5 33.65 48.45 35.2 48.85 35.85 49.45 35.85 50.7 35.85 50.7 34.2 50.7 32.95 50.1 31.95 49.55 30.95 48.85 30.95 L47.1 31.3 44.15 31.4 38.1 31.4 36 31.65 Q35.5 31.9 35.5 32.6 35.5 33.15 36.2 33.45 L37.05 34 Q37.6 35.2 37.6 39.75 L37.5 42.45 37.25 44.4 Q37.05 45.2 36.35 45.6 35.65 45.95 35.65 46.45 35.65 47.45 36.9 47.45 L46.8 47.45 48.55 47.65 49.5 47.7 Q50.25 47.7 51 45.9 L51.65 43.45 51.35 42.3 Q51 41.9 50.5 41.9 50.15 41.9 49.1 43.5 47.95 45.1 44.95 45.1 43.35 45.1 43 44.65 42.7 44.15 42.7 41.95 42.7 41 42.85 40.65 43.05 40.35 43.6 40.35 44.8 40.35 45.1 41.55 45.35 42.75 45.9 42.75 46.6 42.75 47.05 41.75 47.45 40.7 47.45 39.05 47.45 37.4 47.1 36.5 46.7 35.6 46.05 35.6 45.25 35.6 45.05 36.85 44.8 38.1 43.95 38.1 L42.75 37.95 Q42.5 37.8 42.5 37.05 L42.5 35.05 Q42.5 34.2 42.9 33.9 M55.05 32.65 Q53.15 34.25 53.15 36.6 53.15 38.8 55.2 40.3 56.15 41 58.95 42.2 61 43.1 61 43.75 61 44.25 60.45 44.55 L59.05 44.85 Q56.8 44.85 55.5 43.05 54.15 41.25 53.7 41.25 52.7 41.25 52.7 42.55 52.7 45.15 54.05 46.3 55.65 47.75 59.9 47.75 63.15 47.75 65.2 46.2 67.25 44.6 67.25 42.05 67.25 39.65 65.2 38.35 64.4 37.85 61.4 36.8 59.35 36.1 59.35 35.2 59.35 34.65 59.75 34.35 60.15 34.05 60.8 34.05 62 34.05 63.5 35.35 65 36.7 65.65 36.7 66.2 36.7 66.6 36.2 67 35.75 67 35.1 67 34.1 66.2 32.85 65.4 31.45 64.45 31.45 L63.85 31.6 63.35 31.75 61.5 31.3 59.75 31.1 Q56.95 31.1 55.05 32.65 M117.5 61.3 L111.75 61 Q107 61 104.5 61.75 100.8 62.8 100.8 65.6 100.8 66.9 102.85 68.15 104.25 68.9 104.25 69.75 L104.1 70.2 98.1 84.15 97.2 84.4 Q96.25 84.4 96.05 83.9 L90.55 70.55 90.5 70.2 Q90.5 69.45 91.95 68.65 93.6 67.7 93.6 65.9 93.6 62.45 89.2 61.65 L80.95 61 79.7 60.85 78.4 60.85 Q73.8 60.85 70.4 62.3 66.95 63.75 66.95 66.5 66.95 68.15 69.35 69.1 71.6 70.1 72.05 70.95 L76.25 80.65 83.75 98.3 Q87.8 107.75 88.35 107.75 88.85 108.9 90.2 109.55 91.5 110.25 92.95 110.25 96.4 110.25 97.5 107.85 98.4 107.85 104.85 94 110.9 80.85 115.05 70.55 115.75 68.9 118.05 68.35 120.4 67.8 120.4 65.45 120.4 61.95 117.5 61.3 M115.25 32.9 Q115.25 33.5 115.95 33.9 116.65 34.3 116.75 34.65 L116.9 35.5 116.95 36.45 Q116.95 37.9 116.25 37.9 115.9 37.9 115 37.2 114.45 36.75 112.85 35.3 L110.1 32.7 Q109.3 31.95 108.75 31.75 L107.5 31.5 107.2 31.5 106.55 31.5 104.15 31.8 Q102.9 32.2 102.9 33.1 102.9 33.5 103.5 33.85 L104.4 34.5 104.95 36.85 105.15 39.3 105 42 104.6 44.7 103.75 45.45 103.35 46.15 Q103.35 46.9 104.45 47.3 L106.6 47.65 Q108.3 47.65 109.2 47.15 109.9 46.8 110.05 46.05 110.05 45.65 109.65 45.3 L108.85 44.7 108.45 43.4 108.25 41.8 108.45 40.55 Q108.6 40.1 108.9 40.1 109.6 40.1 111.8 42.05 L115.65 45.7 Q117.8 47.65 118.5 47.65 119.25 47.65 119.6 46.5 119.9 45.4 119.9 41.25 L120 37.35 Q120.1 35.8 120.35 34.7 120.45 34.35 120.95 34.1 121.95 33.55 121.95 32.8 121.95 32 120.95 31.65 L119.3 31.45 118.9 31.45 118.75 31.45 118.7 31.45 118.4 31.45 116.45 31.7 Q115.25 32.05 115.25 32.9 M90.55 37 Q90.55 35.9 91.1 35.15 91.65 34.45 92.5 34.45 94.3 34.45 95.45 37.35 96.4 39.7 96.4 41.85 96.4 43 95.85 43.7 95.3 44.3 94.4 44.3 92.75 44.3 91.55 41.35 90.55 38.95 90.55 37 M83.9 36.35 Q83.9 34.1 82.2 32.65 80.5 31.25 77.75 31.25 L73.65 31.5 71.2 31.6 70.55 31.55 69.95 31.55 68.55 31.8 Q68.05 32 68.05 32.65 68.05 33.4 68.75 33.6 70.2 34 70.2 35.75 L70.2 43.2 Q70.2 44.95 69.05 45.5 68.5 45.75 68.5 46.2 68.5 47.7 72.7 47.7 77.15 47.7 77.15 46.15 77.15 45.8 76.35 45.25 75.45 44.65 75.45 43.85 L75.4 41.85 Q75.4 41.45 76.15 41.45 L76.85 41.5 77.8 41.6 Q80.5 41.6 82.2 40.15 83.9 38.65 83.9 36.35 M100 33.75 Q97.45 31.1 93.3 31.1 89.75 31.1 87.25 33.5 84.75 35.9 84.75 39.35 84.75 42.9 87.2 45.35 89.65 47.75 93.2 47.75 97.05 47.75 99.7 45.45 102.35 43.15 102.35 39.75 102.35 36.2 100 33.75 M139.25 33.8 Q140.25 34.55 140.35 35.3 L140.45 37.35 140.45 37.75 140.45 38.15 140.35 40.8 140.3 43.35 Q140.3 44.4 139.1 45.05 138.55 45.35 138.55 45.75 138.55 46.9 139.85 47.25 L142.5 47.5 143.25 47.5 146.05 47.3 Q147.5 47 147.5 46.2 147.5 45.65 146.8 44.95 146.1 44.3 146 43.8 L145.95 42.15 145.85 40.35 146 37.05 146.1 35.1 Q146.1 34.8 147.05 33.9 L147.5 32.95 Q147.5 31.95 146.4 31.65 L144 31.45 143.15 31.45 Q140.7 31.45 139.65 31.95 138.8 32.35 138.8 33.1 138.8 33.45 139.25 33.8 M136.45 32.85 Q135.65 31.45 134.7 31.45 L134.1 31.6 133.6 31.75 131.75 31.3 130 31.1 Q127.2 31.1 125.3 32.65 123.4 34.25 123.4 36.6 123.4 38.8 125.45 40.3 126.4 41 129.2 42.2 131.25 43.1 131.25 43.75 131.25 44.25 130.7 44.55 L129.3 44.85 Q127.05 44.85 125.75 43.05 124.4 41.25 123.95 41.25 122.95 41.25 122.95 42.55 122.95 45.15 124.3 46.3 125.9 47.75 130.15 47.75 133.4 47.75 135.45 46.2 137.5 44.6 137.5 42.05 137.5 39.65 135.45 38.35 134.65 37.85 131.65 36.8 129.6 36.1 129.6 35.2 129.6 34.65 130 34.35 130.4 34.05 131.05 34.05 132.25 34.05 133.75 35.35 135.25 36.7 135.9 36.7 136.45 36.7 136.85 36.2 137.25 35.75 137.25 35.1 137.25 34.1 136.45 32.85 M177.65 155.8 Q176.45 153.75 175 153.75 L171.4 154.4 165.2 154.7 152.6 154.7 148.3 155.15 Q147.25 155.65 147.25 157.15 147.25 158.35 148.65 158.9 150.05 159.45 150.4 160.1 151.6 162.6 151.6 172.1 L151.4 177.7 150.85 181.7 Q150.45 183.45 149 184.2 147.5 184.95 147.5 186 147.5 188.1 150.1 188.1 L170.8 188.1 174.4 188.45 176.35 188.6 Q178 188.6 179.55 184.85 180.85 181.7 180.85 179.75 180.85 178.3 180.2 177.4 179.55 176.5 178.5 176.5 177.75 176.5 175.5 179.85 173.2 183.25 166.9 183.25 163.55 183.25 162.85 182.25 162.2 181.25 162.2 176.6 162.2 174.65 162.55 173.95 162.95 173.3 164.05 173.3 166.65 173.3 167.2 175.8 167.75 178.3 168.9 178.3 170.35 178.3 171.25 176.2 172.15 174.1 172.15 170.65 172.15 167.2 171.35 165.3 170.55 163.4 169.15 163.4 167.55 163.4 167.1 166 166.65 168.65 164.85 168.65 L162.3 168.3 Q161.8 168 161.8 166.45 L161.85 162.3 Q161.85 160.5 162.65 159.9 163.4 159.35 165.85 159.35 172.2 159.35 174.15 162.55 175 163.95 176.25 163.95 178.85 163.95 178.85 160.5 178.85 157.9 177.65 155.8 M173.1 123.45 L172.65 123.45 170.65 123.7 Q169.45 124.1 169.45 124.95 169.45 125.65 169.8 125.9 L170.15 126.3 169.65 127.4 168.95 128 168.9 128 Q168.55 128 168.1 127.4 167.6 126.8 167.6 126.25 L167.95 125.95 168.25 125.4 168.2 125.1 Q168.1 124.4 167.35 124 166.6 123.65 165.75 123.65 L161.8 123.65 160.55 123.85 Q159.3 124.2 159.3 125.05 159.3 125.45 159.65 125.75 160 126.15 160.8 126.45 L162.35 128.05 164.45 131 164.7 131.75 164.75 133.05 164.7 134.75 164.6 136.1 164.1 136.85 Q163.05 137.55 163.05 137.95 163.05 139.15 164.65 139.4 L167.7 139.55 168.35 139.55 169 139.55 170.8 139.35 Q171.65 139 171.95 138.15 L172 137.85 Q172 137.4 171.5 137.05 170.4 136.3 170.4 135.65 L170.4 130.95 174 126.35 175.2 125.9 Q176.05 125.65 176.05 124.8 176.05 123.95 175.65 123.7 175.25 123.4 174.55 123.4 L173.9 123.45 173.25 123.45 173.1 123.45 M165.9 61 L164.2 61.35 161.45 62.1 154.65 60.35 Q151.4 59.55 149.2 59.55 139 59.55 130.85 67.65 122.7 75.7 122.7 85.05 122.7 96.6 130.45 103.5 138.15 110.4 150.5 110.4 164.5 110.4 170.3 101 L173.55 94.1 177.15 92.7 Q178.6 91.85 178.6 90.2 178.6 87 173.95 85.5 170.4 84.35 164.8 84.35 158.15 84.35 154.7 85.35 149.8 86.8 149.8 90.5 149.8 93.3 153.6 93.75 157.45 94.2 157.45 96.25 157.45 98.05 156.35 99.3 155.2 100.6 153.25 100.6 148.8 100.6 144.9 94.55 141.05 88.55 141.05 82.45 141.05 77.3 143.15 73.7 145.8 69.35 150.8 69.35 154.85 69.35 159.1 74.05 163.35 78.75 166.95 78.75 169.15 78.75 170.65 77 172.1 75.3 172.1 72.95 172.1 69.65 170.55 65.75 168.6 61 165.9 61 M165.3 31.5 L163.4 31.4 160.95 31.65 Q159.75 32 159.75 32.95 159.75 33.4 160.4 33.8 L160.9 34.35 160.85 34.5 158.85 39.15 158.55 39.2 158.15 39.05 156.3 34.6 156.3 34.5 Q156.3 34.25 156.8 33.95 157.35 33.65 157.35 33.05 157.35 31.9 155.85 31.65 L153.1 31.4 152.7 31.35 152.25 31.35 Q150.75 31.35 149.6 31.85 148.45 32.35 148.45 33.25 148.45 33.8 149.25 34.1 150 34.45 150.15 34.75 L151.55 37.95 154.05 43.85 155.6 47 Q155.75 47.4 156.2 47.6 L157.1 47.85 Q158.25 47.85 158.65 47.05 158.95 47.05 161.1 42.4 L164.5 34.6 Q164.7 34.05 165.5 33.85 166.25 33.7 166.25 32.9 166.25 31.75 165.3 31.5 M174.1 33.9 L175.65 33.65 Q178.7 33.65 179.65 35.2 L180.65 35.85 Q181.9 35.85 181.9 34.2 181.9 32.95 181.3 31.95 180.75 30.95 180.05 30.95 L178.3 31.3 175.35 31.4 169.3 31.4 167.2 31.65 Q166.7 31.9 166.7 32.6 166.7 33.15 167.4 33.45 168.05 33.7 168.25 34 168.8 35.2 168.8 39.75 L168.7 42.45 168.45 44.4 Q168.25 45.2 167.55 45.6 166.85 45.95 166.85 46.45 166.85 47.45 168.1 47.45 L178 47.45 179.75 47.65 180.7 47.7 Q181.45 47.7 182.2 45.9 182.85 44.4 182.85 43.45 182.85 42.75 182.55 42.3 182.2 41.9 181.7 41.9 181.35 41.9 180.3 43.5 179.15 45.1 176.15 45.1 174.55 45.1 174.2 44.65 173.9 44.15 173.9 41.95 173.9 41 174.05 40.65 174.25 40.35 174.8 40.35 176 40.35 176.3 41.55 176.55 42.75 177.1 42.75 177.8 42.75 178.25 41.75 178.65 40.7 178.65 39.05 178.65 37.4 178.3 36.5 177.9 35.6 177.25 35.6 176.45 35.6 176.25 36.85 176 38.1 175.15 38.1 L173.95 37.95 Q173.7 37.8 173.7 37.05 L173.7 35.05 Q173.7 34.2 174.1 33.9 M200 0 L200 300 0 300 0 0 200 0"/>
  </g>
</svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a responsive inline SVG in your HTML, the SVG shouldn't have width and height attributes.

**Update:**

Maybe It's a bug on Blink (or Webkit). And I tried to use a redraw hack.

https://jsfiddle.net/pbg1g4uv/2/

```
#logowrapper svg {
  position:               relative;
    width:                                  auto;
    height:                                 100%;
    z-index:                                4;
  animation: redraw 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes redraw {
  from { min-width: 1px; }
  to   { min-width: 2px; }
}
```

Comment: That's a fair point, and the only reason I left them in is because I was screwing around to see if it would make any difference. Unfortunately, it doesn't matter if the SVG has a width & height explicitly set or not: Chrome still misbehaves when rescaling. Updated my fiddle & snippet to reflect.

Comment: Ah, I understood. Updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome - that has totally solved the issue - and in Opera too! I didn't think to try a CSS-based redraw, but it's weird that doing a similar thing via a jQuery `resize()` event didn't work in the same way. Solved!

Comment: Opera is also Blink-based browser :)